# Error parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, utf-16

I am trying to parse the string contents of an XML file that contains special characters in to an XDocument for further processing when I keep getting the following error:

> Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 8.

I do not have control over this file. All I can do is parse it from a network share that I have read access to. The file contents are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ns0:SAEErr xmlns:ns0="http://xyz">
<ErrorInformation>olsfdhfaskldhfksajdfkajsf</ErrorInformation>
<OriginalMessage>慐浹湥䥴Ɽ慐浹湥却慴畴䍳摯ⱥ慐</OriginalMessage>
</ns0:SAEErr>
```

The code to parse the file above is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<root>");
        sb.Append(FileUtil.ReadFileContent(fileName));
        sb.Append("</root>");

        return XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: The following code update did it:

```
 XElement body = XElement.Load(fileName);

 return new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "no"), body);
```

Thanks Henk!

Comment: Show the code that you use to load the XML document.

Comment: And also please tell us how you've confirmed that it's really in UTF-16.

Comment: Yes, please show us hex dump of the XML file.

Comment: +Jon Skeet: I do not own or control the file. I was wondering about the utf-16 bit.

Comment: Why are you adding a root-element around perfectly valid xml? It will just break it in this case since your xml-declaration won't be at the top any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the file with `XElement.Load()` I can only reproduce your error after change `utf-16` to `utf-8` in the processing line. So it is indeed an Encoding error.

Edit:

Your code:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<root>");
  sb.Append(FileUtil.ReadFileContent(fileName));  // Encoding ??
  sb.Append("</root>");
  return XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
```

Try:

```
  XElement body = XElement.Load(fileName); 
  XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement( "root", body));
```

Comment: Hi Henk, when I try and use your code snippet for my XML file with the encoding set to UTF-16 I get the following error: "non-white space characters cannot be added to content".

Comment: Did you notice my last Edit? Concerning `new XDocument`